# Lazy Loading implemented but anyhow it made my app slower and response time increased

Tags: angular, performance, routes, lazy-loading

I have implemented the lazy loading but since then it has made my app too slow that at one click my app does not navigate to other page now. It takes 2 clicks when need to perform any action.

loaninfo.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LoaninfoRoutingModule } from './loaninfo-routing.module';
import { LoaninfoComponent } from './loaninfo.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoaninfoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LoaninfoRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class LoaninfoModule { }
```

loaninfo-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoaninfoComponent } from './loaninfo.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: LoaninfoComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoaninfoRoutingModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { CdashboardComponent } from './components/cdashboard/cdashboard.component';
import { LoanoverviewComponent } from './components/loanoverview/loanoverview.component';
import { LoaninfoComponent } from './components/loaninfo/loaninfo.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'cdashboard', component: CdashboardComponent },
  { path: 'cdashboardl', loadChildren: () => import('./components/cdashboard/cdashboard.module').then(m => m.CdashboardModule) },
  {path:'loanoverview', component: LoanoverviewComponent },
  { path: 'loanoverviewl', loadChildren: () => import('./components/loanoverview/loanoverview.module').then(m => m.LoanoverviewModule) },
  {path:'loaninfo', component: LoaninfoComponent },
  { path: 'loaninfol', loadChildren: () => import('./components/loaninfo/loaninfo.module').then(m => m.LoaninfoModule) },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am navigating like this:

```
 <a href="#" class="nav-link text-light px-4 fs-6" routerLink="/loaninfol">Linesheets</a>
```

Comment: Definitely shouldn't require multiple clicks. Try `preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules` (although this partially removes lazy loading advantage)

Comment: Basically without Lazy loading concept, it works well! I was willing to incorporate lazy loading as it is a large app and contains 100 screens approx.

Comment: @BojanKogoj how does using Preload Strategy partially remove the lazy loading advantage? As far as I can find, using both is an optimal set up for most cases. https://prowe214.medium.com/lazy-loading-vs-preloading-modules-which-should-you-choose-85a1fb71a24

Answer (score 2):

The reason is probably that you seem to have created an infinite loop when you configured:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

This statement leads to a routing to the same path, which will then retrigger the routing to the same path. Redirecting to the same path does not make sense. You should either redirect to a different path or don't redirect and render a component.

Comment: No, thats not an issue, I checked.

Comment: Well, then you should profile your application to see wich task take too long.

Comment: each action is not working on a single click, but when I perform that action once again, then it works

Comment: Having a slow app is entirely different than needing two click in order to navigate. You should decide on which of these issues to tackle first